# another two sentences or other two sentences

Tags: pronunciation

another two sentences

other two sentences

another of two sentences

We need other three chairs

We need another three chairs

Would you please show me if they are correct  and if their meaning is the same or introduce me a site or source so that I could get it?

Many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Your first two examples**

> another two sentences
>
> other two sentences

These are both valid phrases, but they are used in different circumstances. *Another* is basically a contraction of "an other", used when the indefinite article would otherwise be used. That is, when the "other" items are not a particular set of other items.

For example,

> The teacher asked us to write 3 sentences, but I wrote **another** 2 sentences to try to get extra credit.

It doesn't matter what 2 other sentences I wrote, just that I wrote two more than were asked for.

> Three of these five sentences are incorrect. **The other** two are correct.

If I have five sentences to start with, and three are incorrect, then it's two specific other ones that are correct.

**Your third example**

> another of two sentences

There are ways for this to be a valid phrase, but it's meaning is not similar to the other examples. Furthermore, in the examples I can think of, it needs context to provide an antecedent for *another* to refer to. For example,

> In my essay I wrote one paragraph of six sentences and *another [paragraph] of two sentences*.

**Your final two examples**

> We need another three chairs[.]

This is a valid sentence.

> We need other three chairs (*)

This is not a valid sentence. Instead we might say

> We've brought 3 chairs from the store room but we still *need **the** other 3 chairs* to seat all 6 of us.

This implies there were originally exactly 6 chairs in the store room.

Comment: First thanks. Nonetheless, could we say "we need another three chairs= we need extra or additional chairs"?

Comment: Yes. "We need another three chairs" and "we need three more chairs" have essentially the same meaning.

Comment: I am wondering the reason why this"Other interesting places to visit include the old harbour and the castle." is correct, but why this one" we need other chairs" is incorrect!!

Comment: "We need other chairs" might be grammatical, but the meaning is that the chairs we have are the wrong ones. They need to be taken away and replaced with different ones. (And it sounds archaic to me.  I'd rather say "we need different chairs")

Comment: Also, "we need other three chairs" is incorrect. I can't explain why but maybe "other" just can't be used with a number but without an article.

Answer (score 0):

You can use "another" before a noun whenever you can use "a(n)" before a noun.
We use "other" before a noun that would NOT need an article.
The rules for "the other" are the same as the rules for "the" + noun.

Usage:
Three of my friends live in Boston. One is a doctor, one is a dentist, and **the other** doesn't have a job. The friend without a job's name is Craig. Craig needs a job. He also has **another** problem: he needs a new girlfriend. His last girlfriend left him because she met **another** man. **The other** man was rich and handsome. I told Craig not to worry about it; there are many **other** girls in the world.

Comment: Thanks. But, what a bout this version"https://www.google.com/search?q=%22other+books%22&oq=%22other+books%22&aqs=chrome..69i57j69i65j0l4.3769j0j7&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=119&ie=UTF-8#q=%22other+boys%22&newwindow=1&tbm=bks&start=10" other boys

Comment: You could see this word"other" has been used many times without any article!!!

Comment: hi nima u can go through this link http://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/other-others-the-other-or-another

Comment: let me know if this satisfies u

Comment: I don't think this is the whole story. For example, we can say "another three chairs" like in OP's example,  but not "a three chairs".